# NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property - Column name with ID

Tags: c#, nhibernate, exception

When I try to execute the below class using ICriteria,

```
if (_userGroupId > 0 && _userId > 0 )
{
   return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(UserUserGroup))
             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserGroupID", _userGroupId))
               .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserID", _userId))
               .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Deleted", false));
}
```

for class

```
public class UserUserGroup
{
    public virtual long UserUserGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual long UserGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public UserUserGroup() {}

    public UserUserGroup(long userGroupId, long userId)
    {
        UserGroupId = userGroupId;
        UserId = userId;
    }

}
```

with Mapping,

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<UserUserGroup> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Id(map => map.UserUserGroupId, "UserUserGroupID").GeneratedBy.HiLo("hibernate_unique_key", "next_hi", "100", "tablename='UserUserGroups'");
        mapping.Map(map => map.UserId,"UserID").Nullable();
        mapping.Map(map => map.UserGroupId,"UserGroupID").Nullable();
        mapping.Map(map => map.Deleted,"Deleted").Nullable();
    }
```

It throws Exception,

> NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: UserGroupID

How to get the property resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of specifying column names in your query, try using your class's properties identifiers (lower case letters at the end):

```
return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(UserUserGroup))
              .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserGroupId", _userGroupId))
              .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserId", _userId))
              .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Deleted", false))
              .List();
```

To avoid this kind of problem in the future, I suggest you use the [QueryOver API](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx), which provides type checking at compilation time:

```
return session.QueryOver<UserUserGroup>()
              .Where(x => x.UserGroupId == _userGroupId)
              .And(x => x.UserId == _userId)
              .And(x => x.Deleted == false)
              .List();
```

Comment: Strange that string value matters in resolving. Just changing the ID to Id worked. Thanks for the timely help.